# Strange output after cast removing constness in C++

Tags: c++, casting, constants

After encountering some cast and `const` issues, I have simplified my problem in a very small code snippet:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int a = 2;
    
    const int* p = &a;
    int* p_bis = (int*)p;
    
    *p_bis = 42;

    
    printf("\na     = %d", a);
    printf("\n&a    = %p\n", &a);

    printf("\np     = %p", p);
    printf("\n*p    = %d\n", *p);

    printf("\np_bis = %p", p_bis);
    printf("\n*p_bis= %d", *p_bis);
}
```

After compiling this in C++17, it gives me the following output:

```
a     = 2                                                                                                                                                                           
&a    = 0x7ffe9924d19c                                                                                                                                                              
                                                                                                                                                                                    
p     = 0x7ffe9924d19c                                                                                                                                                              
*p    = 42                                                                                                                                                                          
                                                                                                                                                                                    
p_bis = 0x7ffe9924d19c                                                                                                                                                              
*p_bis= 42
```

I know that the line `int* p_bis = (int*)p;` is very dirty, because I do a C cast instead of a clean C++ cast, and furthermore I remove the constness with my cast. But What I don't understand however is how is it possible to have 2 values at the same address `0x7ffe9924d19c`. Is it just some undefined behavior, and there is nothing else to understand?

Comment: That's **undefined behavior** for you.  You give the compiler an invalid program, the compiler can do funny things.

Comment: That said, please read the descriptions of the tags that you applied, don't blindly accept those suggested by the website. As a new user, also take the [tour] and read [ask]. Also, for C++, avoid using C-style casts!

Comment: It is just Undefined Behavior. Since a `const` can never change, it is correct for the compiler to see `printf("\na     = %d", a);` and replace it with `printf("\na     = %d", 2);`.

Comment: If you want to understand *why* the undefined-behavior-invoking code is behaving the way it does, you have to go down a level and look at the assembly-language that the compiler outputs.  (do that and you will see the results of the clever optimizations the compiler has made to your code -- optimizations that are guaranteed not to change the user-visible behavior of your program, *but only as long as* your program plays by the rules and doesn't invoke undefined behavior :) )

Comment: The only time you can remove `const' without UB is if the original wasn't `const`  and then had its `const` added.

Comment: OK thank you all for your answers !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While it is perfectly valid to cast a `const` pointer to a non-`const` one, and it also is valid to modify data through that pointer ***if the data was not originally defined as `const`***, it is invalid to do so if the data was originally defined as `const` (which is your case). Changing the value of a variable that was defined as `const` (even through indirection) is **undefined behavior**.

The above applies to any version of both C and C++.

Comment: You could add that even though UB allows for anything to happen, in practice what happens here is that the compiler replaced `a`'s memory read with an immediate value in assembly, or possibly assigned a register to it. The compiler "thought" it could do it because the const keyword allowed it (well, allowed anything actually)

Comment: @Jeffrey I wouldn't want to speculate. Besides, that is not what usually happens. Usually, `const` data is just put in a `.rodata` section that is mapped at runtime as read only, and writing to that causes a segmentation fault.